# Postfix rewrite recipient based on domain

Tags: email, postfix, email-server, rewrite

I'm looking for a postfix configuration to create recipient rewrite rules based on the recipient domain name including catch all for domains not found in the "not rewrite"-list. For example:

- `laber@example.com`, no rewrite and deliver to MX of example.com
- `foo@bar.com`, rewrite to `foo@spam.example.com`
- `<user>@<domain>`, rewrite to `<user>@spam.example.com`

Ideal would be a list of domains which should not be rewritten via Postfix. For now I using a setup without the exception so everything is rewritten:

`recipient_canonical_maps = static:@spam.example.com`

Answer (score 1):

In main.cf add (removing the existing static map):

```
recipient_canonical_maps = pcre:/etc/postfix/rcpt_canonical_maps
```

In /etc/postfix/rcpt_canonical_maps(replace domain1.com etc with your 'good' domains):

```
if !/^(.*)@(domain1.com|domain2.com|domain3.com)$/
/^(.*)@.*$/ REDIRECT ${1}@spam.example.com
endif
```

Please not, i have not tested this, but I'm fairly confident this will do what you require.

Having said that I should stress that it's important to test this in a non-production environment.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you Aaron, your answer helped me a lot. I could confirm the following settings works with my current running postfix setup (stable Ubuntu 14.04).

I've added the following to `main.cf`:

```
# Receive all emails and rewrite the destination because of testing.
recipient_canonical_maps = regexp:/etc/postfix/recipient_canonical_maps
```

My `recipient_canonical_maps` looks like the following:

```
!/.*@example.com/ @spam.example.com
```